# Python not interpreting wildcard * properly?

Tags: python

For some reason, python doesn't seem to recognize my wildcard command using *.r.
A MWE:

```
filepath = "C:/outputs"
os.remove(f'{filepath}/*.r')
```

Python returns the following error:

```
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:/outputs/*.r'
```

I know there are alternatives to using the "*.r" method, such as using a "for file in os.listdir(...): if file.endswith('.r'): os.remove(file)" etc. But the "os.remove('./*.r')" method works in my other python files, so this is just driving me insane. What might be going wrong?

Comment: Because `os.remove` does not do wildcards. Why'd you think it does?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Comment: Didn't know that-- I thought it had worked in another python file, but one of my other functions must've handled it. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Wildcard expansions like that are a feature of the shell, e.g. bash.

Comment: ...and what that means is: `os.remove()` uses the Operating System APIs to remove the path. The operating system does not support wildcards. No operating system does. Shells like `cmd.exe` translate wildcards into lists of absolute paths *before* doing OS API calls, which is why wildcards work in shells. The `glob` module helps you with expanding wildcards into lists of paths in Python.